# Can't enter 2 inputs from user with unknown length of char pointer

Tags: c, malloc, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to get 2 inputs from user with unknown length of char pointer.(Working on dynamically allocating memory) But after entering 1st input with a "space" it doesn't wait for user to enter second input, it only reads one word and then it allows second input.

```
          char *str1;
          char ch;
          printf("Enter a sentence:(Ex: Computer Engineer)");
          str1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
          scanf(" %s", str1);
          printf("Enter a character to search(Ex: g):");
          scanf(" %c", &ch);
          char *result;
          result=mystrchr(str1,ch);
          if(result!=NULL)
            printf("%s",result);
          else
            printf("NULL");
```

Comment: You should [not cast malloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3545273)...

Comment: Consider using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

The second exact same statement of

```
str1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

is redundant, inappropriate and useless. By doing so you allocate another memory space to which `str1` is pointing to; leaving the previous allocated space because of no `free()`ing abandoned but existing in memory.

---

```
char *str1;
str1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

With that call to `malloc()` you allocate memory of the size of a pointer to `char`, usually 4 bytes on most modern systems, not the space needed to store a string like `"Computer Engineer"`. With this definition it is only be able to store a string of `3` characters plus the automatically appended string-terminating null character (4 characters for 4 bytes).

By putting in a string longer than 3 characters by the call to `scanf()`:

```
scanf(" %s", str1);
```

the program will write beyond the bounds of the allocated memory, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) (like it was high-probably happened in your case).

---

You need to allocate enough space to hold the provided strings - in the case of f.e. `"Computer Engineer"` it needs to have at least 18 byte (Note that `sizeof(char) == 1`):

```
char *str1 = malloc((sizeof(char) * 18);
```

or alternatively:

```
char *str1 = malloc((sizeof(*str1) * 18);
```

Note that you can´t put in a white space separated word by using the `%s` format specifier. For achieve that, use `%[` instead:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", str1);
```

Or even better use the more reliable and safer `fgets()`:

```
fgets(str1,18,stdin);
```

---

If you want to allocate memory dependent upon the input of a user, you need to add another input request and variable before allocating:

```
int len;

printf("How many characters the string should have?");
scanf("%d",&len);

char *str1 = malloc((sizeof(*str1) * (len + 1));     // +1 element for null character.

printf("Enter a sentence:(Ex: Computer Engineer)");
fgets(str1,len,stdin);
```

---

Side note:

You do not need to cast the returned pointer of `malloc` -> [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I mistakenly add redundant  "str1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));" line, I don't want to specify the character size of the entered word. I want my program to create it is own memory according to entered input so dynamically.

Comment: @NeverSAYnever I´ve added the user determinate size of the memory allocation requested by you to the answer. Check it out.